# Preg replace issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, preg-replace

I have a page where I pull a specific row from the database where the name equals what I put in the URL, but I want it SEO friendly.

So say I have "David's Print" in the database.

I want to be able to pull it from the database by putting "davids-print" in the URL

I'm using Codeigniter as my framework.

If I need to explain better, let me know

Currently I'm using

```
public function item($name)
{
    $this->data['item'] = $this->db->get_where('items', array('name' => str_replace("-", " ", $name)))->result_array();
    $this->layouts->view('databases/items/single', $this->data);
}
```

But of course that is only for spaces

Comment: This is something that would be done more easily using a search engine like lucene, not the db

Comment: The get_where part of codeigniter, what would I put as the array('name' => $name) ($name field thing)

Comment: You have to store the "slug" in your database. It would be very hard to unslug `"davids-print"` to `"David's Print"`. Edit: yes "unslug" is a word.

Comment: Ok, so as it's being added into the database, I should make it convert it to SEO in a seperate DB field? And just use that as the get_where?

Comment: @unlucky4ever: No, I would store it in the same table (`items`) just in another field like `slug`. You just have to keep the slug in sync if the name can be changed. If adding another field is no option, then you can use a separate table which maps the "name" to a "slug". In the "where" you can just do something like `$this->db->get_where('items', array('slug' => slugify($name))` where `slugify` is the function which creates the slugs. It would be also a good idea to make the `slug` field "unique".

Comment: @vstm: Please post as an answer. I would also suggest CI's `url_title()` function for creating the slugs.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the best to store SEO-friendly site id's or [slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29), as they are called, next to the actual title of your item. It would be hard to convert the slug back to the original title since certain characters are lost.

First add the `slug` field to your `items` table and make it unique so that there is no ambiguity (so each item has its own slug).

The slug is then generated whenever an item is inserted or updated, for example:

```
$this->title = $_POST['title'];
$this->slug = url_title($this->title, 'dash', TRUE);

$this->db->insert('items', $this);
```

If the DB throws an exception because of the "unique" constraint you can try to insert the record multiple times and just add a number to the slug.

Then you can easily search for the item using the slug (`$name` contains the url-part like `davids-print`):

```
$this->data['item'] = $this->db->
    get_where('items', array('slug' => $name))->result_array();
```

Thanks to [Madmartigan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398242/madmartigan) for the suggestion to use [`url_title`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) which comes with CI.

Comment: For the "add a number to the slug" bit, CI's `increment_string()` function is available (although I would prefer to see an error: "slug is taken, choose another"). Also I would suggest to truncate the slug to 90 chars or so (or likewise, show an error that it's too long).

Answer (score 1):

I have an extended router class that will do want you want.

It will parse any controller methods and variables that have '-' and replace them with '_'.

You could then do;

```
public function item($name)
{
    $this->data['item'] = $this->db->get_where('items', array('name' => str_replace("_", " ", $name)))->result_array();
    $this->layouts->view('databases/items/single', $this->data);
}
```

The class (**MY_Router.php**)needs to be put in *application/core* (mind the class extension).

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function set_class($class) {
        $this->class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
    }

    function set_method($method) {
        $this->method = str_replace('-', '_', $method);
    }

    function _validate_request($segments) {
        // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).EXT)) {
            return $segments;
        }
        // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0])) {       
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            if (count($segments) > 0) {
                // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).EXT)) {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            } else {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.EXT)) {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        // Can't find the requested controller...
        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}
```